# Delete all except matched items

Tags: notepad++, regex

I want to delete all the data except matched items from my file. I am using Notepad++

I want to keep everything between <w:t> and </w:t> tags delete rest of the matter.

Sample data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" 
xmlns:cx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex" 
xmlns:cx1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/9/8/chartex" 
xmlns:cx2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/10/21/chartex" 
xmlns:cx3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/9/chartex" 
xmlns:cx4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/10/chartex" 
xmlns:cx5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/11/chartex" xmlns:cx6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/12/chartex" 
xmlns:cx7="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/13/chartex" xmlns:cx8="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/14/chartex" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:aink="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/ink" xmlns:am3d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2017/model3d" 
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
xmlns:oel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2019/extlst" 
xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" 
xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" 
xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" 
xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" 
xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" 
xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" 
xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" 
xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" 
xmlns:w16cex="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2018/wordml/cex" 
xmlns:w16cid="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2016/wordml/cid" 
xmlns:w16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2018/wordml" 
xmlns:w16sdtdh="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2020/wordml/sdtdatahash" 
xmlns:w16se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex" 
xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" 
xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" 
xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" 
xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 w16se w16cid w16 w16cex w16sdtdh wp14">
<w:body>
<w:p w14:paraId="66109096" w14:textId="49D9B7F3" w:rsidR="00D96595" w:rsidRPr="00D96595" w:rsidRDefault="00D96595" w:rsidP="00D96595">
<w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Heading1"/>
<w:spacing w:before="13" w:line="259" w:lineRule="auto"/>
<w:ind w:left="990" w:right="0"/>
<w:jc w:val="left"/>
<w:rPr>
<w:spacing w:val="-2"/><w:sz w:val="96"/>
<w:szCs w:val="96"/>
</w:rPr>
</w:pPr>
<w:r>
<w:rPr>
<w:spacing w:val="-2"/>
<w:sz w:val="72"/>
<w:szCs w:val="72"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:t xml:space="preserve">          
</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_Toc147064115"/>
<w:r w:rsidRPr="00D96595">
<w:rPr><w:spacing w:val="-2"/>
<w:sz w:val="96"/>
<w:szCs w:val="96"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:t>Advanced</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
</w:p>
```

The code
`<w:t>.+?</w:t>(*SKIP)(*F)|.+?` is not finding any match.

Comment: Perhaps you could format that piece of xml over multiple lines so we can inspect it more easily?

Comment: It works for me. How do you use it?

Comment: Did you set "Search Mode" to "Regular expression" and put a check-mark in ". matches newline"?

Comment: I did change the search mode to Regular Expression.

Comment: In the find what text box I am writing the regex code ```<w:t>.+?</w:t>(*SKIP)(*F)|.+?```

On executing the replace, it deletes everything. Ideally it should keep the text between the <w:t> and </w:t> tags

Comment: Have you ticked `Wrap around` and `. matches newline`? When I run `Replace All`, I got a single line : `<w:t>Advanced</w:t>`. Which version of Notepad++ are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RegEx code you mentioned works fine for me in Notepad++ version 8.5.6. I modified the code a bit for the use case with line breaks:

```
<w:t>.+?</w:t>\R(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|.+?
```

You may have missed the single character matches at cursor position visually. It will highlight each character individually when you click **Find Next** button e.g. using the **Find** dialog. So, try to use <kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> type the regex code from above and click on **Mark All** and see what happens as shown in the screenshot below. Please note, this is depending in color preferences from your settings.

[image]

A click on <kbd>Replace All</kbd> is resulting in:

[image]

Comment: I am using version 8.2 of Notepad++

I used the command ```<w:t>.+?</w:t>(*SKIP)(*F)|.+?``` with Mark All. It works but in normal find and replace it just puts the cursor after every character on clicking Find Next.
I could not understand this behaviour.